# Cannot Use Openshift Client Tools

Tags: java, ubuntu, openshift, ubuntu-10.04, openshift-client-tools

I am having a hard time with the **OpenShift client tools on Ubuntu**. It keeps asking for a password which I am now confused about. **Issuing rhc apps command** displays the following message : Please sign in to start a new session to openshift.redhat.com.
I entered my openshift account password but got a message that it was invalid. What password is required here ??

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-l` param to be sure you are using your account:

```
rhc domain show -l yourmail@mail.my
```

Use the same credentials that used in the web site.

BTW, If you use only an OpenShift account, the setup will configure the access with certificate and you won't need use password from command line.

```
rhc setup
```

Answer (score 0):

It should use the same username/password that you log into the web console with.